# Should users be reported for deleted comments?

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags, behavior

If a user leaves a rude or offensive comment and then deletes it, should there be a way flag or report the message?

For instance, let's say that a user leaves an offensive comment. Someone sees that comment and goes to report it to a moderator. But before they can, the user deletes their own post.

What's the proper response in this scenario? It could be argued that, since the comment was removed, there's no longer a reason to make a report. On the other hand, the user never gets reported for posting offensive content.

Comment: You can always flag one of their post and explain what is going on. If they don't have posts, flag one of your own. Abusive comments, deleted or not, should be made aware to moderators. They have the tools to investigate if there is a pattern.

Comment: Is this about me? I think this is about me. This is about me, isn't it? This is about me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, depending on whether this is one-time or occurring repeatedly, my response would differ.

It's not at all uncommon for some user to get angry everyday, shout "U SUCKS THIS SITE STUPID" and delete their own post. I wouldn't worry about this; it usually happens, the user undoes their own harm and their post was most probably bad anyway.

If I felt they would be repeating the behavior, and I see I can spend some time, I'll watch their posts if it happens again, and this time I would flag their post, or another comment, or whatever is not deleted, and explain **in detail**; because this raises an alarm about vandalism. Mod flags, A.K.A. custom flags, are prioritized in the mod flag queue, and they will be handled soon enough.

Note that I don't have any data, but I can confidently assert that most of these comment deletions aren't by those users, but by flaggers (not even mods, unless they come by them), especially considering that certain keywords cause the comment to be delete-able by a single 'rude' flag.

So to answer your main question, in most of the cases, **no**, there's no need for such a way, since it was most probably moderators (in the general sense) doing their work. It would take a really proficient and persistent troll to write a post, then add offensive comments to pester users but delete them afterwards, in a way that prohibits effective moderation.

Comment: Moving on is probably a good idea. Some user getting angry then deleting their own post is a fairly apt description of what prompted this post.

Comment: As an example:  I do that on occasion; usually on account of a momentary impatience, i.e. “You idiots”.  Then I remember (though not always that same hour) that compassion and patience are traits of the stronger person, and that this junk on the internet is a mere trifle anyway.

Comment: There are some people that get rude in their post itself. For example, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292456/question-demotion-problem/292466#292466) post was really rude (I found it rude, with words like _idiots_). However, the post was closed with the reason: __Unclear what you ar asking__. There was no reference to any inappropriate language in the post. What do you think I should do, flag the post again, this time as being disrespectful?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I don't have 10k rep here so I can't see what the post contained, but when the post contains enough offensive content to be completely inappropriate for respectful discourse, per flag definition, you can flag it as rude/abusive.